# Trello Permissions Question

Tags: trello, permissions

I have a question about Permissions for a Trello board.

Is it possible to set Permissions so that a particular member can COMMENT on a card, but not be able to MOVE a card?

Just wondering as this is something I'd like to be able to control for a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting can be available to one of the following:

- the public (anyone with a Trello account)
- the organization that the board is in
- members of the board

The ability to move cards is available to anyone that is a member of a board

So, you can achieve that if:

1. The board is in an organization
2. The "particular member" is in the organization
3. Commenting is available to organization members

Comment: Wouldn't this solution mean the member could BOTH move and comment? The OP wants comments allowed, but not moving??

Comment: @stuart that would only be true if the member was a member of the board; in this case they are not (so they cannot move cards), but they are in the organization that the board belongs to (so they can comment, because org members are allowed to comment, even if they aren't members of the board)